# How to redirect SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log to log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

The log4j2 website doesn't provide much information on JUL Adapter. Can we re-direct `SystemOut.log` and `SystemErr.log` to log4j2?

Comment: I find your question unclear. The [documentation for JUL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.9) states, "The default configuration establishes a single handler on the root logger for sending output to the console." So what do you mean by "Can we re-direct SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log to log4j2" ? The JUL adapter routes all logging from JUL through log4j2 as long as you configure it correctly by setting the system property java.util.logging.manager to org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager